# Is there a way to execute more than one query per string in MySQL-Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have some input which is a string containing more than one MySQL queries, such as `USE some_db; SELECT * FROM some_table;`. When I store this string as `s` and  `run cursor.execute(s)`, it prints out `0L` and when I do `cursor.fetchall()` it returns an empty tuple. It does not raise any exception, but it does not work either. When I split the string into two queries and open a cursor for each and execute, it works, but correctly splitting a string into queries is not easy, especially when there are comments. Is there a way to avoid splitting and execute the whole string of multiple queries? Or this there a good library to split a string of multiple queries into strings with one query each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for MySQLCursor.execute().

It claims that you can pass in a `multi` parameter that allows you to run multiple queries in one string.

> If multi is set to True, execute() is able to execute multiple
>   statements specified in the operation string.

`multi` is an optional second parameter to the execute() call:

```
operation = 'SELECT 1; INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (); SELECT 2'
for result in cursor.execute(operation, multi=True):
```

Comment: I think this is mysql.connector, not mysql-python.

Comment: That would then change the advise to "switch to mysql.connector instead of mysql-python" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, a Python script can run multiple SQL statements from a string or list, external .sql or .txt file that can be sourced to MySQL.

However, the `cur.execute` command runs one SQL line one at a time. Hence, you will need to loop through each SQL line iteratively. So, consider splitting the multiple SQL commands by semicolon.

```
s = "USE some_db; SELECT * FROM some_table;"

# filter() removes trailing empty list item
s = filter(None, s.split(';'))

for i in s:
    # strip() removes leading and trailing white spaces  
    # semicolon is re-added per line for query run
    cur.execute(i.strip() + ';')
```

But be sure to remove any semicolons found in comments.

```
# PROCESSING STEP 1;
# PROCESSING STEP 1
```

Comment: That code is dangerous for constant strings that include semicolons, and doesn't work that well for parameterized queries (which should be almost all your queries.)