# How to execute more than once the same query with different data?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm trying to execute the same query but with different data but I always get data the first time. The others times, dispite of there are data for the querys in the data base, mysql returns empty data.

This is the code:

```
def get_team_colour_map(self, players, id_competition):
    tcm = FIBAColourMap()
    for p in players:
        args = [p["id"], id_competition]
        conn = pymysql.Connect(host = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_HOST,
                                      user = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_USER,
                                      password = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_PSWD,
                                      db = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_NAME,
                                      charset = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_CHARSET,
                                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            print("id player: {}".format(p["id"]))
            print("args: {}".format(args))
            cursor.execute("select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team pt, tbl007_game g, tbl004_jornada j, tbl012_competition c where pt.id = %s and pt.id_player_feb = sc.id_fiba and sc.id_game = g.id and g.id_jornada = j.id and j.id_competition = c.id and c.id = %s", args)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            print("data: {}".format(data))
            print("Total rows: {}".format(cursor.rowcount))
            if cursor.rowcount > 0:
                for s in data:
                    x = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_x(s["x"]))
                    y = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_y(s["y"]))
                    color = tcm.image.getpixel((x,y))
                    color = ("#%02x%02x%02x" % color).upper()
                    if tcm.exists_color(color):
                        if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                            tcm.set_scored_shots(color, 1)
                        else:
                            tcm.set_failed_shots(color, 1)
                    else:
                        if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                            tcm.set_scored_shots("OTROS", 1)
                        else:
                            tcm.set_failed_shots("OTROS", 1)
            else:
                #tcm = None
                print("Jugadora con id: {} NO ha realizado ningún tiro en competición: {}".format(p["id"], id_competition))
    return tcm
```

In this code, cursor.fetchall() returns data the first query but the next querys returns empty results.

How can I run several querys? I'm using mySQL 8.0 and Python 3.6

Comment: Take a look at `executemany`

Comment: Doesn't work to me :( Always return me 0 rows :(

Comment: Look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106612/is-there-a-way-to-execute-more-than-one-query-per-string-in-mysql-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you are using the same cursor each time. create a new instance of the cursor each time you loop through to excecute the query. After the first query is run the cursor is already positioned after all the data. Hence no rows returned after that

You can also try this:

Look at the documentation for MySQLCursor.execute().

It claims that you can pass in a multi parameter that allows you to run multiple queries in one string.

If multi is set to True, execute() is able to execute multiple statements specified in the operation string.

multi is an optional second parameter to the execute() call:

```
operation = 'SELECT 1; INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (); SELECT 2'
for result in cursor.execute(operation, multi=True):
```

Comment: But, how can I create a new cursor? I think that I'm creating each time the loop is done it. If I close the cursor afted getting the data, I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: Try to reform your code so you can run multiple statements at once. Then make a string that contains all the queries you want to run seperated by comma. 

operation = 'SELECT 1; INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (); SELECT 2'

Then loop through them like this
for result in cursor.execute(operation, multi=True):