# Django DB connection custom SQL parameters

Tags: python, django, django-database

I need to perform a batch update since the ORM [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) seems to be a bit slow for a 1000 records. Since I am updating strings that could contain single quotation marks, e.g. **Mc'Donald**, I cannot simply template a string variable with all of the attributes.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) recommends the following:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
```

**Question:** How do I apply this correctly for the below use case?

**Technical Details:**

- Django 3.0.2
- PostgreSQL

I am generating a SQL string and then calling it as follows:

```
from django.db import connection

people = [{"name": "Person A", "age": 15, "height_m": 1.83, "id": 5}, {"name": "Person B", "age": 19, "height_m": 1.73, "id": 45}]

sql = ""
params = []
for p in people:
  sql += 'UPDATE people SET name = %s, age = %d, height_m = %d WHERE id = %d;'
  params.append(p['name'])
  params.append(p['age'])
  params.append(p['height_m'])
  params.append(p['id'])

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  cursor.execute(sql, params)
  cursor.connection.commit()
```

This throws the following error:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) at index 104
```

Comment: for which column you are getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL queries in Python, always use `%s` as the placeholder, even for integers.

```
sql += 'UPDATE people SET name = %s, age = %s, height_m = %s WHERE id = %s;'
```

Note that for multiple statements, the answer may depend on which database you are using (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106612/is-there-a-way-to-execute-more-than-one-query-per-string-in-mysql-python/31107292) is for MySQL).